# BlackBerry 10 Background Service

Tags: blackberry-10

Is there any way in BB 10 to autostart an aplication at phone startup ? And if it is, is it possible to reamin in background while doing background processing like cheking gps location or wifi status?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot currently run as a headless app in the background (ie, you need a UI), or autostart on device boot.

If the user has launched your app, it can request to still run when not in the foreground. It can also be launched through the push and invocation framework.

Comment: can it also be launched through the push and invocation framework by itself after installing or running for the first time? Let`s take for example an alarm clock. Or an application that scans the gps and saves the route all the time.

Comment: The push frame work requires the action of an external server to push data to the device; the invocation framework requires another to request a service provided by your application. So the short answer is no, you can't currently implement an alarm clock or route tracker.

Answer (score 3):

As of BlackBerry 10.2 you can do this using Headless Apps. More information here: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/headless_apps/

Comment: and even [deferred](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2014/12/deferred-autorun-headless-app/)